# Python Float to 16, 12, bit values

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding, bit

I am trying to track down a rounding error. We have a black box which we pass numbers to it as floats and they are then stored in memory inside the black box for future use. Whenever we read them out they are **always** different. We have been told that they are either being stored as 16 or 12 bit values. I am looking to write a quick python script that will perform the conversion to both 16 and 12 bit values and back again so that we can compare what we put in to what we got out of the box. I am not sure where to start with this so any assistance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

NumPy has [16-bit floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format). There is, AFAIK, no standard for 12-bit floats.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.float16(1.234567890123456789)
1.2344
```

Comment: do you know of a way to possibly do it roughly even if its converting to binary and back again?

Comment: There is no such thing as "converting to binary". They start out as binary, and they remain binary the whole time.

Comment: sorry I meant to 12bit binary

Comment: First you need to figure out what representation is being used. Without that you may as well just pick a random 12-bit number and use that.

Comment: fair enough, I guess I hadn't thought about that part